# Why do we "test" pupils on "rules" of English when English has no legal standards board?

Tags: writing-style, language-evolution

English is a fluid language.  So, of course, we want to teach kids to write, but what's the point of grading them on it?  Absent a board of standard dictated by law as exists for some other languages, I don't see the point.  With less emphasis in school on correctness, our language can be more fluid yet, with style guides keeping up with common usage rather than compelling common usage.  It would be interesting to see whether the English language would improve as a form of communication if allowed to evolve unimpeded.

Note: Edited to remove my irrelevant comment about spaces after periods.

Comment: What do you mean no standards??  There are dozens!!!  Oxford, Cambridge, Webster, Macmillan, and so on.

Comment: *"A great example is the sudden rush to delete one of the two spaces after a full stop, even though it makes text harder to read."* - "Harder to read" is a matter of opinion, and in practice the idea of two spaces only applies when typing, whereas typesetting used to use a single wide space, and spacing would be varied to provide fully justified alignment. (I still almost always type two spaces between sentences, but that's just force of habit.)

Comment: If you can teach it you can grade it.  And if you can’t grade it, then you can’t teach it.

Comment: “English has improved during the 21st century.” Evaluate and explain your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is less the hard *rules* and *standards* and more the *Practice of* English as it is currently spoken. All here will admit that it is a moving target but then so is science and history. The tests given are only to affirm that the students have picked up the most recent lesson imparted to them and have not given up on the previous.

By way of English evolving unimpeded, it actually has, all this time. The rule used to be that there is *Standard* English and *Non-Standard* English. Plenty of non-standard people do just fine in their own way. Reliable communication on the other hand takes disparate people with common needs and provides them a currency of understandable speech. When usage eventually demands it then the language will unapologetically subsume the new usage and call it its own.